# How to get Visual Studio Intellisense to recommend an Async variant of a method

Tags: c#, async-await, intellisense

As a library developer I will often create a `Async` and `Non-Async` methods when it makes sense to do so. What I find however is that often a developer consuming my library will use the non-async method while inside a method that is already asynchronous.

How can I get visual studio (or maybe resharper???) to the developer that there is an Async version, and that it's recommended in this situation? I'm hoping there is an attribute I can put on the methods.

Example:

```
public async Task DoSomething()
{
    var result = MyLibrary.Run(variable); // <- this should be var result = await MyLibrary.RunAsync(variable, cancelationToken);

    var businessLogicResult =  doBusinessLogicOnResult(result);

    await someHttpCallThatIsAsync(businessLogicResult);
}
```

Comment: Are the non-async versions of your methods actually completely rewritten to be completely synchronous? Or are they just wrappers around your async methods?

Comment: Take a look to the [EditorBrowsableAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: It is not very obvious why they can't pick the Async version when they just typed the `async` keyword.  Some reason to assume they'll always pick Aardvark over Zebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code Analyzers (aka Roslyn Analyzers) are the way to go. It's possible to write your own, specifically for the way you expect people to use your library. You can add them as a dependency for your library, so they get included automatically any time someone uses your library. That would give you a lot of flexibility, but require more work than just adding an attribute to your code.

Alternatively you could recommend that people use a more general-purpose set of analyzers (e.g. [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers) has a "[Call async methods when in an async method](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/master/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD103.md)" that sounds like what you're going for). You could even depend on that analyzers library directly, but you'd have to consider how your consumers would feel about your library causing them to get analyzer errors for other unrelated parts of their code. And while it's generally a good idea to use Async methods when you can, there are cases where you don't want to. Entity Framework has some serious performance degradations when using `ToListAsync()` if you're reading large column values like `nvarchar(max)`, for example.

Comment: I found a number of Analyzers that helped identify a slew of issues and helped me fix them en-mass as well. I'll be keeping these in my go-to grab bad.  This one was exactly what I was looking for: https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/master/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD103.md

Answer (score 2):

You can build Roslyn analyzers to supply with your library.

Start here: [Get started with Roslyn analyzers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-roslyn-analyzers)

If you want to see examples, this is a good resource: [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers)